# A better way to union two excel tables

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables

A  B  C
name  surname  address

and

A  B  C  D
id  address  name  surname

I need to union the tables and matching the cols, so
table1, colA = table2, colC
table1, colC  = table2, colB
etc

I use this code, which works fine, but for big data is slow

```
Sub unionrep()

Dim lastRow As Long

Sheets("decl").Select
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Sheets("onl")
    tlastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
End With

 For i = 1 To lastRow
 Sheets("onl").Range("a" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = Range("a" & i).Value
 Sheets("onl").Range("b" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = Trim(Range("b" & i).Value)
 Sheets("onl").Range("c" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = "*" & Range("c" & i).Value
 Sheets("onl").Range("d" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = Range("g" & i).Value
 Sheets("onl").Range("e" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = Range("d" & i).Value
 Sheets("onl").Range("f" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = ""
 Sheets("onl").Range("g" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = ""
 Sheets("onl").Range("h" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = ""
 Sheets("onl").Range("i" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = Range("e" & i).Value
 Sheets("onl").Range("j" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = Range("i" & i).Value
 Sheets("onl").Range("k" & tlastRow + i + 1).Value = Range("f" & i).Value

 Next

 Sheets("onl").Select
 End Sub
```

Comment: Your Question narration is not matching to your code. Your code will write data of selected columns of ~decl~ sheet to ~onl~ sheet after the existing data on ~onl~ sheet without matching of column values. Pl state your objective clearly with sample data presentation and output desired to be obtained from the program code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy and paste the entire ranges instead of looping through the rows. For example, to copy from column A in the "decl" sheet to column C in the "onl" sheet, something like:

```
Sheets("decl").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Copy
Sheets("onl").Range("C" & tlastRow + 1).PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using arrays:

```
Sub unionrep()

    Dim lastRow               As Long
    Dim vDataIn, vDataOut

    With Sheets("decl")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
        vDataIn = .Range("A1:I" & lastRow).Value
    End With

    ReDim vDataOut(1 To lastRow, 1 To 11)

    With Sheets("onl")
        tlastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        vDataOut(i, 1) = vDataIn(i, 1)
        vDataOut(i, 2) = Trim(vDataIn(i, 2))
        vDataOut(i, 3) = "*" & vDataIn(i, 3)
        vDataOut(i, 4) = vDataIn(i, 7)
        vDataOut(i, 5) = vDataIn(i, 4)
        vDataOut(i, 9) = vDataIn(i, 5)
        vDataOut(i, 10) = vDataIn(i, 9)
        vDataOut(i, 11) = vDataIn(i, 6)

    Next
    Sheets("onl").Range("a" & tlastRow).Resize(UBound(vDataOut, 1), UBound(vDataOut, 2)).Value = vDataOut
    Sheets("onl").Select
End Sub
```